# Tree shaking dependencies in Blazor wasm app

Tags: asp.net, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly, tree-shaking

I'm trying to understand the various release mode linking / trimming / tree shaking options for a blazor wasm app.

It seems tree shaking reduces the size of referenced .NET dlls. Does it also:

- Trim my app's dll
- Trim dependencies' dlls

I'm especially interested in the dependencies. Supposing we need a handful of libraries for various use cases, the size increases very quickly.

If dependencies cannot be trimmed, what is the reason - why can SDK dlls be trimmed, but others not?